# Restoring from Yosemite Time Machine backup on Mavericks

Tags: macos, time-machine

Is it possible to restore a Yosemite backup to Mavericks? I downgraded and want to access my most recent restore, or else I'll have to use the Mavericks one from a month ago.

I am on a Macbook Pro 13-inch mid-2011.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's unlikely that this will work - and any software that was updated will probably not understand its settings file (e.g. Mail, Messages and the like). Also, restoring everything would replace system files with Yosemite versions.

You could go into Time Machine and pull out documents and content you have created/updated while running Yosemite, and that should work OK. But restoring settings and the system is highly unlikely to end happily.

Definitely not recommended.

Comment: What about settings files for apps that were not built by apple? would those work?

Comment: Yes, those should work just fine as long as you have the same version of those programs on Mavericks now.

Comment: Ah.  That just made my life a lot simpler.

Comment: Great! Glad to hear it :)